# Dropdownlist Checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

If you have ever used SQL reporting services, there are some dropdown lists that pop down with a checkbox list in it. It allows a user to select multi items very nicely. Does anyone know a free User control or an example of this implemented. Ok, so I know I can do this with some elbow grease and html, was just trying to see if there was already something out there. I’m using ASP.NET C#.

Thanks,

Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out.

1. http://www.metabuilders.com/Tools/CheckedListBox.aspx
2. http://forums.asp.net/t/1040242.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Ok, posted here to soon. I use infragistics and found a possibe solution.

Thanks!

http://forums.infragistics.com/forums/t/3962.aspx